# Add Inkwell to Card

Tags: flutter

I have the below card:

```
Card(
    semanticContainer: true,
    clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
    child: Image.network(
        item['thumb'],
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
    ),
    shape: BeveledRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
        topLeft: Radius.circular(24),
        ),
    ),
    elevation: 0,
);
```

I wish to add clickable inkwell functionality.

I have attempted the following, however the images no longer fit into the cards:

```
Card(
    semanticContainer: true,
        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
            child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                    Image.network(
                        item['thumb'],
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                    InkWell(
                        splashColor: Colors.grey.withAlpha(30),
                        onTap: () {
                            print('Card tapped.');
                        },
                    ),
                ]
            ),
        shape: BeveledRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(24),
            ),
        ),
    elevation: 0,
);
```

how would I be able to preserve the card height and width constraints and clip the image (using BoxFit.cover) so that the second example looks visually the same as the first - with the added inkwell functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put your image inside `InkWell` like this:

```
Card(
  semanticContainer: true,
  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
  child: InkWell(
    splashColor: Colors.grey.withAlpha(30),
    onTap: () {
      print('Card tapped.');
    },
    child: Image.network(
      item['thumb'],
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
    ),
  ),
  shape: BeveledRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
      topLeft: Radius.circular(24),
    ),
  ),
  elevation: 0,
);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Inkwell` required the child to perform a click event on it, so you are missing child there.

Example:

```
   InkWell(
          onTap: (){print("Clicked on Container");},
          child: new Container(
            width: 200.0,
            height: 200.0,
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following way to use the onTap property.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.light,
        primaryColor: Colors.red,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(title),
        ),
        body: InkWell(
          splashColor: Colors.grey.withAlpha(30),
          onTap: () {
            print('Card tapped.');
          },
          child: Card(
            semanticContainer: true,
            clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
            child: Image.network(
              item['thumb'],
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
            shape: BeveledRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(24),
              ),
            ),
            elevation: 0,
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, you might need to wrap your `InkWell` in a `Material`. This might be needed in some cases to be able to see the ripple effect.

So something like,

```
Material(
   child: InkWell(...)
)
```